# Poor performance

Tags: performance

working with a startup that has an app with thousands of users. last two releases to Test flight have resulted in crashes. don't know the cause since the App works flawlessly on my end. I also have no one to ask questions about the code base.

How does this situation look from someone whose been in the industry?

Comment: Are you the sole programmer on this? Given your experience, they ought to have hired at least one more dev to be the senior.

Comment: @Kozaky yeah. I've done a good job of following the design patterns already in place, but its deeply unfortunate I have no one to ask questions.

Comment: **"Works flawless on my end"** is a classical software industry catch-phrase, there's t-shirts with that. Welcome to the wonderfull and painfull word of software development

Comment: This is slightly off topic for this question, but OP, seriously investigate something like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) or [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/), it'll get you the logs you need to diagnose these bugs automatically without needing users to report the issues to you

Comment: Might depend on how you word it. Apps are hard to debug given iOS version, and Android version and incompatible background apps. A bit off topic but try to get your bosses and stakeholders to become "testers." That way if your app fails, you can word it to the effect of, "Let's get this working on your phone."

Comment: Also as a rule of thumb, try to compile the app to the lowest possible OS version that meets your requirements. Generally speaking that will help alleviate most incompatibilities and "works on my phone" comments. Ask the stakeholders to be "beta testers" for a week or two to iron out bugs.

Answer (score 5):

Third sprint of a startup company with one developer? It should not surprise them that there are a few issues on launch. And that isn't a criticism of your development skills, even a startup should have hired a more experienced developer to give you guidance and offer second opinions on your coding.

Being the sole developer will have its benefits too. If your colleague(s) come from no development background, *YOU* are the one best placed to suggest setting aside a sprint to work on live bugs before any further work can be done. If they have been trusting with you up until this point, I would be confident you can make your case that time be spent on research and fixing bugs so that they don't become bigger issues in the future.

Given your description - especially of their 'full trust' in you - it doesn't sound as if they are looking to fire you. They may be aware of your inexperience and expect some growing pains. I've known some startups to take on relatively new developers as a kind of 'investment'; you might not have spent many years in the field but it will pay off in the long run for everyone to have you there from Day 1.

Comment: Good way to tell if they are going to terminate you is if they start interviewing new developers. Very doubtful they'd fire you without a replacement since you're the sole developer.

Answer (score 1):

Speak with your team lead and try to get the technical issues resolved as well as possible.  Learn from your colleagues about how to diagnose and solve these kinds of problems.

You're there to learn - you're not there to be fired as soon as something doesn't go right first time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP has commented that they're the sole programmer on this project.

Comment: So ask people outside of the team.  Gather what info you can and ask on StackOverflow or the relevant stack for the platform.  A company can't/shouldn't employ a junior dev as their **only** dev and without expecting to suck up a few hits along the way.

Comment: OP can starts asking on StackOverflow =)

Answer (score 0):

> How does this situation look from some one whose been in the industry?

You caused a problem in a live app, fix it, do whatever is necessary including using your personal time. This is what I would expect from a dev.

Roll back until it works and then get busy fixing the crash in a lab environment, if you can't make it crash there then analyse your lab to see what the differences are from live because therein lies your problem.

Having problems is understandable, not having a resolution strategy and rolling back immediately the problem is recognised isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem isn’t in the live app, since my front end changes would have to be release in App Store to go live.

Comment: Then it is your lab I would think

Comment: Kilisi: I _think_ OP means the version (with the problems) hasn't "gone live" (so the one that's "out there" still works, so it's not _as_ critical as a "_problem in a live app_"). To @AnonProgrammer: as others have said, the first priority is to determine the differences between the testers' environment and yours. Do this as calmly and methodically as you can. Every dev has code that goes wrong; what matters more is how you go about fixing it.